# How to add a MouseDragEvent listener when drag on the Axis X?

Tags: javascript, charts, lightning, lightningchart

I am trying to add a MouseDragStart listener when drag on axis x, but I can not find related API in lightning API document, can anyone suggest me which API should I use?
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUDNg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to attach an event to MouseDragStart on the axis.

If it's enough for you to know when the axis scale has changed, then you can attach a listener to the [`onScaleChange`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.0.0/classes/axis.html#onscalechange) event. This event is fired when the start or end value of the axis changes.

Comment: by the way, i meet a problem  that number on axisx is a little fuzzy， i noticed that lightningchart is canvas,  i want to know whether lightningjs support svg or not,  and how can i fix this probleem

Comment: We are aware of the fuzzy text issue and are working to fix it in a future release. LightningChart JS doesn't support SVG.

Comment: hello,Snekw,   how can i change Themes after  created a chart?  i only find that themes should be setted when creat a chart  in API Doucmention, but how about after created?